# Struggling with rotate and itemize

Tags: itemize, rotating

as the title suggest, I encountering some trouble with the association of the package rotating and the use of itemize :

I would like to have my text rotated right next to my list but this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern,marvosym}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\usepackage{rotating}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\fontfamily{ptm} \Huge Les 5 commandements}
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.001em}
    \begin{turn}{90}
Objectifs
    \end{turn}
\end{minipage}

\columnbreak
\noindent

\begin{minipage}{10em}
       \begin{itemize}
        \item Blabla
        \item Blabla
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}



\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

produces that result (**updated !**) :
[image]

Whereas I would like it to look as that one (the rotated one) :

[image]

How could I stick the list to the rotated text ? 
Thank you !

Comment: You can not keep an empty line between the minipages otherwise you will get a new paragraph.

Comment: Try this: `\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{1em}\hfill   \begin{turn}{90}Objectifs
    \end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.925\textwidth}
    \noindent\begin{itemize}
       \item Blabla
       \item Blabla
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}`

Comment: We are looking better but still not what I look for !

Comment: note that `rotating` package `turn` environment is just a thin wrapper around the standard `\rotatebox` command, for compatibility with documents written with the 1980's `rotating` package for latex2.09. It works Ok but there's not a lot of need to use it this century:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal space is due to the itemize. If you use a normal paragraph you'll see that the space is smaller.

[image]

```
\noindent\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{Objectifs}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.7\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
       \item \lipsum[1]
       \item Blabla
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\noindent\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{Objectifs}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.7\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
```

Changing the anchor for rotating and the base point for minipage produces a better view, with the rotated text aligned to the top.

```
\noindent\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Objectifs}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
```

[image]