# Problems with enumerate inside rotate

Tags: enumerate, rotating

I'm creating a Q&A exercise set where the answers are in upside-down (rotated 180) text. I have the following code, where I have an `enumerate` (with an `item` for every Q&A answer) inside a `rotate`. I followed the examples from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations).

```
\usepackage{rotating}

.....

\begin{rotate}{180}
\begin{enumerate}
\item It will produce 500, one for each of the original features.
\item The answer is False.
\end{enumerate}
\end{rotate}
```

However, this code won't even compile with `pdflatex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.980 \item I
             t will produce 500, one for each of the original features.
```

I tried both `rotate` and `rotatebox` as described in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203485/struggling-with-rotate-and-itemize).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a paragraph like environment for `enumerate` to work.  Just wrap it in a `minipage` or `\parbox`.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{rotate}{180}
  \parbox{0.4\linewidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item It will produce 500, one for each of the original features.
    \item The answer is False.
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{rotate}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

## EDIT

I suggest you should use `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx`-package.  It enables to define the origin of rotation.

Therefore the MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{180}{
  \parbox[t]{0.6\linewidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item It will produce 500, one for each of the original features.
    \item The answer is False.
    \end{enumerate}}}
\end{document}
```

And the result, especially for wider boxes is:

[image]

## EDIT 2

As requested, the solution with `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{180}{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item It will produce 500, one for each of the original features.
    \item The answer is False.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

The result is identical to the one before, so no extra image here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please also show how I could use `minipage` instead of `parbox`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I am glad, I could help.  Here you are, as requested, an example with minipage.